# Jenkins - how to specify gradle task list in freestyle project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using **gradle plugin** for **Freestyle** project.

How to specify the task list in the textarea of **tasks**?

Should I separate the tasks by comma like: `clean, build` or ` separate them by spaces or newline?

I am not able to find the instructions on **Jenkins Gradle Plugin** wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks are specified in a space separated list (so `clean build` is the correct way) as in the picture below. [image: Tasks example]

If you click on the little button to the right the text box expands to multiple lines (each task that is currectly listed will be placed on it's own line). You can then specify a task per line (this can make long task lists a bit more readable). When you save the configuration it will be folded back into a single line.